# UIAutomator runs 0 tests when built on Linux, but works fine on other platforms

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, android-uiautomator

I'm having an issue getting tests to run using the UIAutomator libraries for Android in Linux.  The basic setup is a Nexus 4, or an Emulator with 4.2.2, JDK6, Eclipse, and Linux Mint 13.

The root of this issue is:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=
Time: 0.007

OK (0 tests)


INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
```

This is what I get when I create the jar file under Linux.  If I build it in Windows or OSX, everything seems to work swimmingly.  In this specific case, there is only one test, which is to press the 'home' button.

If I create the project with the same code, and same steps under either other environment (osx/windows), the test runs as expected.

My question is - why would the test runner not be able to find the class when the jar is created under Linux, as opposed to the platoforms?  My best and only guess right now is that somehow the java path is not being set correctly when compiling, so the jar file is built incorrectly.  When running the tests from within Eclipse, I originally had gotten 'ClassNotFoundException', whereas on osx/windows the tests would run in JUnit, but fail.

I dug into this, and found the compilers were all pointing to different java versions on different parts of the system.  I fixed this, deleted everything but one instance of java6jdk, and checked JAVA_HOME, eclipse build paths, and java compile paths all point to the same instance.

After all of this, the tests still seem to build, but the test runner cannot find them.  I'm at the end of my knowledge here, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Edits:
jar tvf:

```
spicy@ubuntu:~/workspace/TestOne/bin$ jar tvf testui1.jar 
0 Sun Apr 07 14:23:24 PDT 2013 META-INF/
103 Sun Apr 07 14:23:22 PDT 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
1052 Sun Apr 07 14:23:24 PDT 2013 classes.dex
```

The code:

```
package com.test;

import android.util.Log;

public class FirstTest extends UiAutomatorTestCase {

    public void thisTest() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        getUiDevice().pressHome();
        Log.i("HELP","HELP ME");
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you compared the jar files?

Comment: bit for bit, no - I opened them up in vi to compare to make sure they were at least similar, and of what little plaintext was in there, they seemed to contain the correct paths.  They were also about the same size.  Is there a better way to compare jar files?  Is there a way I can analyze the contents to check what is contained within?

Comment: you can unzip the jar files to find out what they contain. Then you can use diff (a command line utility on linux, etc) to compare each file you have unzipped with the same file name unzipped from a working jar file. Can you also post the code for your test case in case there's a quirk with the name of the test, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After way too much work and effort, I'm embarrassed to report that the issue was in the naming of the test function.  If the functions start with 'test_', then the automator finds the tests.  If it doesn't start with 'test_' it ignores them.

Gah!

Comment: In your original question you said your tests worked in Windows and OSX, but didn't run if they built on Linux. From your answer I'm guessing the operating system wasn't the problem at all, and you had different source files on Linux too - which would explain why you had the symptoms you report. FYI you're not the only person to trip up over the naming of the tests here. I expect the Android test runner uses reflection (in Java) to find which methods to treat as tests. My, possibly simplistic view is the tests need to confirm to JUnit 3 rules.

Comment: On Windows compilation at least, you need to clear the uidump.xml in your selected target folder if you rename or otherwise substantially change a jar file, otherwise it may lead to test issues.